# MySQL Master and Replica different size of files

Tags: mysql-5.7, master-slave-replication

Recently I noticed that my replica and master storage is quite different. To be exact replica takes 250GB more.

Both are dedicated servers, both are exact specs, both have exact disk drives and storage size and both run ONLY MySQL.

I did some digging and here is a sample table that I found which is WAY larger on the replica than on the master.

```
root@mysql-replica:/mnt/mysql_replica_storage/platform# ls -lah activity.ibd
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  609G Jan 24 20:55 activity.ibd


mysql> show table status like 'activity';
| 928123 |           1199 |   1113587712 |               0 |   1009451008 |   6291456 |      369071211 | 2020-09-22 04:19:10 | 2021-01-24 20:49:23 |


mysql> select id FROM activity order by id desc limit 1;
+-----------+
| id        |
+-----------+
| 369074671 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and here is on the master:

```
root@mysql-master:/mnt/mysql_storage/platform# ls -lah activity.ibd
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  468G Jan 24 12:53 activity.ibd


mysql> show table status like 'activity';
| 322081458 |            636 | 204979830784 |               0 | 249514033152 |   5242880 |      369071211 | 2020-09-22 04:19:09 | 2021-01-24 20:49:24 |

mysql> select id FROM activity order by id desc limit 1;
+-----------+
| id        |
+-----------+
| 369074671 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I stripped down the output to the different columns. Names are:

```
Rows, Avg_row_length, Data_length, Max_data_length, Index_length, Data_free, Auto_increment, Create_time, Update_time
```

There are no queries running on the master/slave, or stuck queries in any state, especially not on this table.

Also the replica is not used in any way. Not even for reading.

I'm still trying to figure out what could be the issue of this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems table on slave isn't consistent with master's table. I think if you query number of records on both sides, it will be different.

Checksum of the table could be useful but for a huge table it takes much time, moreover if table changes continously it isn't a good way to compare them.

In my opionion rebuild of slave would be the solution. Was there any brake with replication? Any skipped transaction?

Could you share log positions of both sides?

Comment: Nothing broken, or skipped transaction. One thing I remember doing (to this table in particular) was : ALTER TABLE RENAME TO and then CREATE TABLE LIKE.

As far as the positions and logs here they are:

Comment: `mysql> show master status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
File: mysql-bin.024271
Position: 300349474
Binlog_Do_DB: platform
Binlog_Ignore_DB:
Executed_Gtid_Set:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: `mysql> show slave status\G
Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.024271
Read_Master_Log_Pos: 300349474
Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.072413
Relay_Log_Pos: 300349687
Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.024271
Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 300349474
Relay_Log_Space: 300349941
Master_Info_File: /mnt/mysql_replica_storage/master.info
SQL_Delay: 0
SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: have we done any delete operation then optimize table on both side and check.

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA don't have experience with optimize table on such big table 400+ GB table ... Might freeze the server. but not sure :(

Comment: YOu can run false alter which will not freeze server but definitely slows down system performance as operation will consume CPU and disk IOPs. but if we do heavy delete operations then we should optimize table once a month atleast.